# Typescript error:Object.fromEntries typescript Error

Tags: angular, typescript, object

I have a function in typescript which uses Object.fromEntries to reduce a complex response object and group it using substring of the child object key.

```
let Newresult = res.map(object => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(object).map(([key, value]) => [
key,
value.map(valueobject => Object.entries(valueobject).reduce((res1, [name, value]) => {
    const key = name.slice(0, 5);
    res1[key] = res1[key] || {};
    res[key][name] = value;
    return res1;
}, {}))
])));
```

but the problem is typescript throws below error while compiling.

```
error TS2339: Property 'fromEntries' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'.
error TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type '{}'.
```

I tried adding ESNext,ES2017.Object into my tsconfig.json lib-array but still its throwing compilation error.
but the same updates for my lib-array is allowing me to use Object.entries.

I am using angular -v-6, typescript:~3.1.1

which other method can help me achieve the same result as above.
can somebody direct me in right direction?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 10):

`Object.fromEntries` was [ES2019](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html), so your `lib` option needs to include that (or ES2020). (ESNext is a moving target.)

That said, TypeScript v3.1.1 is fairly old. You may need to upgrade.

Comment: but adding ES2019 to my lib Options is throwing more errors.
as of now my tsconfig.json target is set to "es5".

Comment: This is an existing angular code, and upgarding typescript is not an option. hence looking for a alternative @t-j-crowder

Comment: Well, TypeScript v3.1.1 was [released Sep 2018](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/releases?after=v3.1.6), so I'm a little surprised adding `ESNext` to `libs` didn't work, since `fromEntries` was very far into stage 3 at that point. If you're really shipping to ES5-level browsers, you will of course need a polyfill.

Answer (score 4):

- TypeScript version is 3.9

Open tsconfig.json

Add

```
"target": "esnext",
"lib": ["esnext", "dom"]
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I've tried setting both lib and target to esnext, es2019, es2020, and I keep getting the error message on Object.fromEntries.  --- Property 'fromEntries' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the `lib` compiler option to 'es2019' or later

Answer (score 0):

In your `src/polyfills.ts` file, you just need to uncomment the following line:

`import 'core-js/es/object';`

Place before the zone.js import. This should fix this specific issue, but depending on what other statements and functionalities of modern browsers you use, you may have to uncomment more imports.