# How to store map values into an array to its first position using typescript?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, collections, maps

I have a map and want to store map values into an array but to its first position only.
My map is:

```
this.mapValues.set("1","First");
this.mapValues.set("2","Second");
this.mapValues.set("3","Third");
```

Then afterwards I want it to convert it in form:

```
[{1:First, 2: Second, 3: Third}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure of the required functionality here. Why exactly use a `Map` only to convert it to an object enclosed in an array later.

Nevertheless, you could use `Array#reduce` with `Array#from` and spread syntax to convert the map to an object. Then later enclose it in an array.

```js
let mapValues = new Map();

mapValues.set("1","First");
mapValues.set("2","Second");
mapValues.set("3","Third");

const arr = [Array.from(mapValues).reduce((acc, curr) => ({ 
    ...acc, 
    [curr[0]]: curr[1] 
}), Object.create(null))];

console.log(arr);
```

Note: `Map`s can have non-string keys, object literals can't. In your case however it shouldn't be an issue.

Edit: Alternative to other solution when `Object#fromEntries` isn't available.

Answer (score 2):

I think something like

`const myarray = [Object.fromEntries(this.mapValues)]`

might do what you want

(see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries#converting_a_map_to_an_object)

I'm not sure that all maps can be converted to objects, since maps can have any kind of value as keys, but in the case of your example it should work.

Comment: Object.fromEntries is a javascript feature, hence it should be available in typescript aswell, since typescript is a javascript superset


EDIT: if your typescript version is too old, it may lack the method definition, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62201724/typescript-errorobject-fromentries-typescript-error

Comment: Yes, saw that so this isnt working for me any other solution ?